# How to keep my html design using ngDialog

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-dialog

I am using ngdialog to get modal popup. I can't able to find anything which will keep my modal design(modal.html). My modal is somehow get twisted by default desigen. 
My code is:

```html
ngDialog.open({
            template: 'adm03/sendMessagePopUp.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                // controller logic
            }]
            });
```

My dialog comes like this
[Twisted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z00cf.png)

but it comes like

[should come like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQdt.png)

Comment: your css file was not loaded

Comment: When i am removing ngdialog dependency. It is working fine. I am using ngdialog because i need some functionality from it.
I think css file working fine.